# MySQL update many-to-many tabel relation

Tags: mysql, many-to-many

I have tables A and B and A_has_B where have this fields:

A: id, name

B: id, name

A_has_B: a_id, b_id, background

Previously when I had not 'background' field in A_has_B, I did update by delete all record in A_has_B and reinsert updated records.

but now how can I update A_has_B whitout deleteing records that should reinsert?

Comment: could you please clarify your question please

Comment: when I had not 'background' field, I was able to delete all records of given a_id from A_has_B and then reinsert all new records, but now if I do this, user should reupload background image for Previously checked a_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the top of my head, I would think something like....

```
DELETE FROM a_has_b
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM b
  WHERE b.id=a_has_b.b_id
);
```

(and similar for table 'a')

or

```
DELETE FROM a_has_b
WHERE b.id <> ANY (SELECT id FROM b);
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you just need to

```
update A_has_B
set background = ???
where a_id = ??? and b_id = ???
```

You'll have to fill in the missing bits.